# Disable next button and prev button in Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, carousel

I am using jquery carousel in my application like

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
     var j = jQuery.noConflict();
     j(document).ready(function () {
         j('#pagination').jcarousel({
             wrap: 'circular'
         });
         var count = $("#pagination li").size();
         if (count < 10)
         {
             j(".jcarousel-prev").addClass("jcarousel-prev-disabled");
             j(".jcarousel-next").addClass("jcarousel-next-disabled");
         }
     });

     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

     prm.add_endRequest(function() {
         var j = jQuery.noConflict();
         j(document).ready(function () {
             j('#pagination').jcarousel({
                 wrap: 'circular'
             });
             var count = $("#pagination li").size();
             if (count < 10) {
                 j(".jcarousel-prev").addClass("jcarousel-prev-disabled");
                 j(".jcarousel-next").addClass("jcarousel-next-disabled");
             }
         });
     });
   </script>
```

Now the issue is that it doesn't make next button and prev button disabled if there are li items less than 10...
Please help!!!

Comment: is that classes you are adding in if condition works with next previous button ?

Comment: please create a jsfiddle and share

Comment: Please tag/link the plugin you're using. What does this has to do with jQuery ui?

Answer (score 0):

Add css to your class like

```
.jcarousel-prev-disabled, 
.jcarousel-next-disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

**Updated**

Use `$("#pagination li").length` instead of `$("#pagination li").size()` and your problem will solve.

Comment: I have already added css. my question is that the above code doesnot work if items are less than 10...

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the jQuery carousel plugin and created the example below for you.The example below will disable the prev & next buttons.If you want to completely hide them you can use `$(".jcarousel-control-next").css('display', 'none');`

```
   <head>
    <title>Basic carousel - jCarousel Examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_shared/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jcarousel.basic.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousel.basic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            var imageCount = $("#images li").length;                    
            if(imageCount < 10){
                $(".jcarousel-control-next").css('pointer-events', 'none');
                $(".jcarousel-control-prev").css('pointer-events', 'none'); 
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
            <div class="jcarousel">
                <ul id="images">
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img1.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img2.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img3.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img4.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img5.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img6.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img1.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img2.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="../_shared/img/img3.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
            <p class="jcarousel-pagination">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```